# Unable to serve django static files using uwsgi server to the nginx reverse proxy

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi as the server and nginx as the reverse proxy for running the django project.

Project structure is as follows(here i have listed only required folder/files):

```
war
├── katana
│   ├── wapps
│   │   ├── app1
│   │   └── app2
│   └── wui
│       ├── settings.py
│       └── wsgi.py
└── static
    ├── css
    │   └── test.css
    ├── img
    │   └── test.img
    └── js
        └── test.js
```

The static configuration in settings.py is as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10242880
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
```

The wsgi.py is as follows:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "katana.wui.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The uwsgi is server is started using:
`uwsgi -b 65535 --socket :4000 --workers 100 --cpu-affinity 1 --module katana.wui.wsgi --py-autoreload 1`

The nginx conf is as follows:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    include     conf/mime.types;

    # the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
    upstream uwsgi {
        server backend:4000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    }

    # configuration of the server
    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      8443 ssl http2 default_server;

        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name _; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        charset     utf-8;

        ssl_certificate     /secrets/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /secrets/server.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

        # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        error_page 497 https://$http_host$request_uri;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  uwsgi;
            include     /config/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
    }
}
```

The project deployment is successful but the static contents(css,js,img) are not loading.
Error in the browser console:

```
GET https://<ip>/static/css/test.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Note: I want uwsgi server to serve the static files and nginx to just act as a reverse proxy. If nginx is configured to serve static files then it is able to do it but i want this functionality to be achived using uwsgi server.

Comment: Show us your ngnix conf

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production

Comment: ngnix conf updated in the question

Comment: If you really want Django to serve static files instead of Nginx, you could look at [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html).

Comment: Just noting out that if you are not planing to use CDN in future it will still preform considerably worse than nginix

Comment: So in production scenario,you guys suggest me to use uwsgi as application gateway and Nginx to act as a reverse proxy and also serve static files?

Comment: Yes, if you are using a reverse proxy like Nginx or Apache, then you would usually configure it to serve the static files, unless you decided to use a separate CDN.

Comment: @iklinac and Alasdir, these issues could be overcome by configuring Nginx to cache the static content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not serve static files in production you should add aditional nginx location for them

```
location /static {
        alias   /path/to/your/static/;
    }
```

---

I would advise not to do following as you are already proxying from nginx, there is no point of uwsgi handling them ( you get bit more load this way as they need to be proxied back)

If you still want to go this path uwsgi [staticfile](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StaticFiles.html) docs

Comment: Thanks, i am using uwsgi to serve static files and i will be configuring nginx to cache these static files into it.